# Offset Error in RubyMine SQL Scratch File

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rubymine

All of a sudden I am getting the following error when trying to run any SQL query via RubyMine.  I am connected to a Snowflake database.

`offset 0, count -1, length 16384`

I've been using the same database and same setup in RubyMine for years.  No issues until this randomly popped up today.  Does anyone understand the error or have advice on resolving it?

I tried disconnecting from the database, creating new connections, writing new queries, etc.  Nothing has resolved the issues.  Others in my organization are not experiencing this.

Comment: Please inspect the logs in Help - Show Log in Files and Help - Show Log in Files. If the error message doesn't bring you any further, feel free to report this issue on our tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE